# Does heteroskedasticity matter if you have a large enough sample?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, heteroscedasticity, central-limit-theorem

Let's say you run a regression with over 200 observations.  Would this reasonably large sample mitigate the impact of residuals heteroskedasticity as an offshoot of the Central Limit Theorem, or something similar.  As a result, the statistical significance of the regression coefficients would not be in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the answer depends on the method that you are using. If you want to justify the usual $t$-tests, $F$-tests and confidence intervals when fitting a linear regression model using just an ordinary least square method (OLS), then the answer is NO. You need homoscedasticity to justify above mentioned tests and C.I.

However, heteroskedasticity-robust procedures are valid (at least in large samples) regardless of the heteroskedasticity or homoscedasticity of the residuals. So in this case, the answer would be Yes!

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly... Does heteroskedasticity matter if you have a large enough sample? Yes, it does.  Does a large enough sample mitigates the heteroskedasticity issue? No, it does not.  And, calculating robust-Standar Errors and other methods like WLS, etc... works well to correct the heteroskedasticity.  Did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly.